# Moving admin-related files out of their models and controller folders and into a separate admin folder in Rails. How to organize this code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a legacy app with 100s of related admin models, controllers, services, jobs, etc. We decided to move all of these files in a folder at the top-level of the app directory called admin. So our ideal file structure would be:

`app/admin/models/admin.rb`
`app/admin/controllers/admin_controller.rb`
`app/admin/services/admin_service_of_some_kind.rb`
`app/admin/models/audit.rb`
`etc`

We want the call sites in our code to be:

`Admin::Admin.create...`
`Admin::AdminService.retrieve_all_audit_logs...`
`Admin::Audit.scope_by_admin...`
`etc`

The problem is that after reading these links:

http://urbanautomaton.com/blog/2013/08/27/rails-autoloading-hell/
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html

I understand that Rails infers file path names from the constants. So if I want to call `Admin::AdminService.some_task`... Rails will believe the Admin constant and the nested AdminService constant would exist in a file at (assuming that app/admin is autoloaded... which I believe it is) `app/admin/admin_service.rb` which is not true... they exist in `app/admin/services/admin_service.rb`.

How can I make this happen given that I want the call site to be `Admin::AdminService.some_task`?

Given the folder structure of `app/admin/services/admin_service.rb`, the call site would have to be `Services::AdminService.some_task` right? (this assumes that `app/admin` is autoloaded) right? However,  this is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just move them into

```
app/models/admin/*.rb
app/services/admin/*.rb
```

Comment: People don't want it that way. Also, it's more clear I think that if everything is nested under `app/admin/models` and `app/admin/controllers`, it is less clear that this is separate business logic. But mainly, people have agreed this is best.

Comment: People as in employers? I don't know of any way to make rails autoload the files in this way. You can change autoload paths but you can't just skip one of the folder names in the lookup. I think what they are asking of you is impossible. I don't see any reason why having all of the admin related code in app/admin makes it any more clean than having it in the normal locations namespaced under admin